# java generics interface extending itself

Tags: java, generics

I am going though some pre-written code & am not sure what would be the intuition behind implementing something like this where an interface extends itself:

```
public abstract class ServiceProviderLocator {
....
         public interface ServiceProvidersInstantiator<T> extends ServiceProviderInstantiator<T> {

              public List<ServiceProviderInstantiator<T>> providers();
         }
....

}
```

Any thoughts?

Please advise,

Thanks!

Comment: The interface being declared appears to be plural: `ServiceProvidersInstantiator` vs. the interface its extending: `ServiceProviderInstantiator`.

Answer (score 3):

`ServiceProvidersInstantiator`  is not equal with `ServiceProviderInstantiator`

Bad naming though.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I agree its a bad naming. This was just a piece of code i came across while browsing some code which caught my attention.